# Submit form to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need help with submiting data form #send_form to #f_from in another page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function post_form() {
    $('#send_form').action = "form01.html";
    $('#send_form').submit();
    return false;    
}
</script>

<form id='send_form' action='form01.html' method='POST' onsubmit="post_form();">
<input type="text" name="f_in01" value="User" />
<input type="text" name="f_in02" value="12345" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The form01.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function f_res()
{
    var res01=document.f_form.f_in01.value;
    var res02=document.f_form.f_in02.value;
    var result = res01 + " " + res02;
    document.f_form.f_out01.value=result;
}
</script>

<form id="f_form" onSubmit="f_res();return false;">
<input type="text" name="f_in01" /><br>
<input type="text" name="f_in02" /><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" onClick="f_res();" value="Enter w/Sub" /><br>
<input type="text" name="f_out01" />
</form>
```

Now it doesn't work. The data doesn't post in page01.html

Comment: That made very little sense. Please add some more detail and clarification.

Comment: Um, you do realize that if you are going to make a POST request to URL "form01.html", your HTTP server needs to handle that somehow? You can't just serve a static file "form01.html" and expect it to magically know what form data was submitted upon requesting it. Are you expecting the data to be present somehow in the <input> elements of form01.html just because they have the same name attributes? That's not quite how HTTP/HTML works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#send_form').attr('action', "form01.html");
```

instead of

```
$('#send_form').action = "form01.html";
```

check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaURk/)

Comment: Thx. I did. But it's still don't post data to other page.

Answer (score 0):

Amin is right, but in jQuery, when an event handler returns false, it amounts to the same as `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation()`. Essentially, you cancel the event. Try returning true, instead of false.

If you don't want the page to change, you'll have to look at AJAX to post the form data.

Answer (score 0):

You want AJAX for this something like:

```
    $('#button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST", //php method
    url:'process.php',//where to send data...
    cache:'false',//IE FIX
    data: data, //what will data contain (no SHIT Sherloc...)

    //check is data sent successfuly to process.php
    //success:function(response){
    //alert(response)
    //}

    success: function(){ //on success do something...

    $('.success').delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);

    //alert('THX for your mail!');
    } //end sucess 
    }).error(function(){ //if sucess FAILS!!
    alert('An error occured!!');
    $('.thx').hide();
    });
    });
```